# not validating special character "_" in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

hello i am using javascript to validate field

i am checking special characters.. the code i am implementing validates all the special characters except   _  underscore..

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function validateForm()
{
    var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?_";

   for (var i = 0; i < document.reg_form.txtusername.value.length; i++) 
        {
            if (iChars.indexOf(document.reg_form.txtusername.value.charAt(i)) != -1) 
                {
                    alert ("Special Characters are not allowed.");
                    return false;
                        }
         }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

for this filed

```
<input name="txtusername" type="text" id="txtusername" maxlength="10" style="background-color:#CCC"  />
```

but its not validating the underscore

Comment: Do you understand the code at all...?

Comment: yes i do.. and i tried to put underscore in iChars.. but its not validating the underscore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

characters in strings can be addressed as if the string were an array (which, if you think about it, it is). Since you're looping through the string char-per-char, again, as you would with an array, why not be consistent in your logic?

```
if (iChars.indexOf(document.reg_form.firstname.value[i]) !== -1)
{
    alert('Foobar');
    return false;
}
```

That should work... Also: there's no real need to escape the single quote, since the iChar string is delimited by double quotes... if all else fails, you might want to try omitting that backslash, too. Though I don't think that's what's causing the problem

It is working: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GvQC5/)

Comment: i just implement your and same problem is here that its still not validating underscore :(

Comment: Glad to know it helped, would be glad to see this answer accepted, too :)

Answer (score 2):

Would it not make sense to just shove it into your iChars variable, which is quite obviously your "blacklist"?

```
var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?_";
```

Comment: @maham It has to work. Have you saved the file, uploaded it, and made sure that the newest version of your page is being served?

Comment: i have updated the code.. plz check why it is not validating underscore

Comment: no its not.. i tried alot .. it validates all characters except `underscore`

Answer (score 1):

```
var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?_";

        for (var i = 0; i < document.reg_form.firstname.value.length; i++) 
        {
            if (iChars.indexOf(document.reg_form.firstname.value.charAt(i)) != -1) 
                {
                    alert ("Special Characters are not allowed");
                    return false;
                 }
         }
```

Comment: i put underscore at the end but its not validating :( @blasteralfred

Comment: try this `var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\:<>?_";`